# Core Data fetch request grouped by related attribute

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm quite new to Core Data so please forgive me if I get any of the terminology wrong.

I'm trying to find the bestselling items of my open orders.

I have an entity called 'OpenOrder'. It has a to-many relationship called 'items' to the entity 'Item'. Item has attributes 'quantity' (Int32) and 'categoryName' (String) — this is basically the item name.

I have a predicate that filters which open orders I want to use. This part is working fine. There's also processed orders which have items. This is one of the reasons I don't just want to get all Item entities.

I would like to get an an array of dictionaries with the categoryName and total quantity of each.

So I'm setting up my fetchRequest like so:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "OpenOrder")
```

Setting up a sum of quantity:

```
let sumExpression = NSExpressionDescription()
sumExpression.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "items.quantity")])
sumExpression.name = "itemsQuantity"
sumExpression.expressionResultType = .integer64AttributeType
```

At the moment, I'm just trying to get this part working, so I'm just fetching the sumExpression:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [sumExpression]
```

Setting the result type of the fetchRequest:

```
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
```

And doing the actual fetch:

```
... = (try? managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)) as? [[String:Any]]
```

This results dictionary in the following format:

`[["itemsQuantity": 1], ["itemsQuantity": 4], ["itemsQuantity": 2]...`

I want the quantities grouped by product, so I added a groupBy:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["items.categoryName"]
```

But now I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong exactly. Is this something Core Data can do and how would I go about going that?

Many thanks.

Comment: what is this `items.categoryName` ? is `items` a `oneToMany` relationship?

Comment: Sorry @brahimm, but this was over two years ago and I don't work for the same company anymore so can't remember anything about this.

Comment: yeah I noticed the date :D . but it just sad to see a question without answer or comment :p